# How to add column with specific condition for oracle DB

Tags: sql, oracle

How do add a field – DOC with Date type to the Registration table.
Also DOC (Date of Completion) should be greater than DOJ (Date of joining).

I wrote this query but it is showing error : Column check constraint cannot reference other column

```
ALTER TABLE Registration add DOC date CHECK(DOC > DOJ);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add both the DOC column and the CHECK constraint with a single ALTER TABLE statement (see [DBfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d4d270143800cac5c97a9686fa156b0c) here) :

```
-- table for testing
create table atable( doj date ) ;


alter table atable
add (
  doc date
, constraint checkdoc check( doc > doj ) -- cannot be coded *inline*
);


-- testing -----------------------------------------------------
-- this insert must succeed
insert into atable( doj, doc ) values ( sysdate, sysdate + 1 );

-- this insert must fail due to the CHECK constraint
insert into atable( doj, doc ) values ( sysdate + 1, sysdate ) ;
-- ORA-02290: check constraint (...CHECKDOC) violated


-- table/data --------------------------------------------------
select * from atable ;
DOJ         DOC
03-JUN-20   04-JUN-20
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the constraint at table level instead of column level.

For example:

```
SQL> create table t(x number, doj date);

Table created.

SQL> alter table t add doc date;

Table altered.

SQL> alter table t add constraint check_doc check (doc > doj);

Table altered.

SQL>
```

Comment: Table is already exist. and constraint at table level is new to me.
Can't we do this in single query?

Comment: No. You need to run 2 ALTER TABLE statements. Is this an issue for you ?

Comment: Yeah, I can fire only single query on db for optimisation.